# How to put spaces between bars in ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to put spaces between each pair of bars in my barplot.

This is my code

```
ggplot(Germ, aes(x = G, y = T, 
             fill = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
             position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
theme_minimal() + 
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
labs(color = '')
```

This is my barplot

[image]

It would like to add the space of a bar, or even less, bewteen, bars pairs 1,2 and 3,4, and so on.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is with 'sneaky facets':

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(within(Germ, fac <- (as.numeric(G) - 1) %/% 2),
              aes(x = G, y = T, 
                  fill = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9), linewidth = 0.3) + 
  guides(fill = 'none') +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  +
  facet_grid(.~fac, scales = 'free_x') +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

It's probably worth pointing out that the bars here are going all the way up from 0 to the *maximum* value of `T` for each value of `G`. This *might* be what you intended, but it's unusual, and you might be looking for `stat_summary(geom = 'bar', fun = 'mean')` in place of `geom_bar` (if you need bars at all, which seems doubtful). Note as well that `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is just a long way of writing `geom_col`.

---

**EDIT**

If you want lines connecting the medians, you will need to switch to a numeric x axis with bespoke labels and calculated x axis positions, which is harder, but can be done like this:

```r
ggplot(within(Germ, {
    grp  <- c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)]
    xpos <- as.numeric(factor(G)) + 0.4 * ((as.numeric(factor(G)) - 1) %/% 2)
  }), aes(x = xpos, y = T, fill = grp, color = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = 'identity', color = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9), linewidth = 0.3,
               aes(group = G)) + 
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = 'median', 
            aes(color = )) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue'), guide = 'none') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = rep(0:11/2.5, each = 2) + 1:24, labels = 1:24,
                     name = 'G') +
  guides(fill = 'none') +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

### [image]

**Data used**

There was no data supplied in the question, so I have had to attempt to approximate it. This was considerably harder than answering the actual question!

```r
set.seed(1)

Germ <- data.frame(G = rep(factor(1:24), each = 10),
                   T = rnorm(240, 4 * rep(1:24, each = 10) * 
                               rep(rep(c(1, 1.2), 12), each = 10),
                               rep(seq(0.5, 12, 0.5), each = 10) * 
                               rep(rep(c(1, 1.2), 12), each = 10)))

Germ$T <- ifelse(Germ$T > 100, 100, Germ$T)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!
I have one last question: is there a way to connect the median of the bloxspots with a line (red medians with a red line and blue with blue)?
And Im sorry about the missing data.

Comment: @AndréLima no, you can't put lines across facets without a great deal of difficulty. You would need a bespoke x axis on a single plot to do this, which is possible but considerably more complex.

Comment: @AndréLima see my update for how you could achieve this.